# WordPress.com Stats plugin is requiring login, and redirecting to WordPress.com on login

Tags: plugins

I have my own private installation of Wordpress

I've installed the [wordpress.com stats plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbuwX.jpg), so I get a stats feature like you get on the free wordpress blogs, its nice and simple, and works well

Now on my blog, all I can see on the plugin (on my dashboard) is a login screen, and when I try to login it redirects me to my free blog (which I had to setup to get an API key)

**Why has my plugin suddenly started requesting a login? It has been working fine for 2 weeks now**

The login it expects is the login of my free blog, and when I do provide those credentials it redirects me to my free one.

Screenshot of what I see on my dashboard :[image]

Tried to de-activate and re-activate plugin, no luck

Comment: Also I have 2 wordpress logos in the menu bar, it seems its rendering extra items from the free WP login page...strange. I have not touched blog since this morning and all was fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WordPress.com Stats plugin is broken as of this morning. It doesn't work on any of my sites and if you click this http://twitter.com/search/WordPress%20Stats You'll see lots of people are finding it borked this morning.

You may have to wait a few days and try again once the issue is fixed.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the link. Just as I clicked people were saying its backup :)

Comment: yup I just turned it back on and it seems to be working fine again.

Comment: *@curtismchale* - Nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

This happens from time to time to me as well, though less frequently lately.  Steps I take† to fix:

1. Go to WordPress.com and log out
2. Log out of your blog
3. Clear your cache
4. Log back in to your blog

That seems to fix it for me.  It seems to be a problem with my browser interpreting the login from one site as a login to the other and passing the wrong data when requested.  I say "seems" because there very well could be another cause of which I'm unaware.

† Steps I take means that this works for me, on my server, with my specific site configuration.  They may work for you, they may not ...

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that doesn't work for me. (same behaviour viewing on iphone). It seems only the "Dashboard" page is affected, all other pages seem OK

Comment: Could you have another plug-in interfering with the system?

Comment: Seems the answer was related to curtis' post. +1 for the help, thanks! :)